# Gradle dependencies declaration format (Groovy)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

What are the differences between dependencies declaration format in Gradle using Groovy e.g.

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: "${springBootVersion}"
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
}
```

What is the recommended format to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is using `group:name:version` notation and the second the map-style notation. Both achieve the same result in the end: declare a dependency found in an artifact repository.

There are a variety of ways to declare dependencies, refer to the API docs for thorough details: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html

It boils down to personal preference as to which one you use. They do the same thing so it really doesn't matter which.

Generally, you will 90% see the second one: `group:name:version` notation